# Show that $A^{i+1}=nA^i$ for all $i \geq 1$ where $A$ has $1$ as all of its entries.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, field-theory, solution-verification

**Question:** Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix over a field $F$ whose every entry is equal to $1$. Show that $A^{i+1}=nA^i$ for all $i \geq 1$. Deduce that $A$ is a nilpotent matrix iff $\text{ch}\ F|n$.

**Attempt:**

For $i=1$, We have $A^2=(a'_{ij})_{n \times n}$ such that $a'_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^na_{ik}a_{kj}=n$, i.e. $A^2=nA$. Hence, it is true for $i=1$.

Suppose it is true for $i= k$.

Now, for $i=k+1$, we have $A^{k+2}=AA^{k+1}=A(nA^k)=nA^{k+1}$. Hence, it is true for $i=k+1$ as well. Hence, by the Principle of Mathematical Induction, $A^{i+1}=nA^i$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$.

Suppose that $A$ is a nilpotent matrix, i.e $A^k=O_{n\times n}$ for some $k>1$ [$k \neq 1$ since $A$ has $1$ as all of its entries and in a field $F$ $1\neq0$.]

Now, $A^k=n^{k-1}A=O_{n\times n} \implies n^{k-1}=0$. Now, $\text{ch} \ F=u $ (say) is a prime number. Suppose $u \nmid n^{k-1}$. We have by division algorithm, $n^{k-1}=mu+r$, where $m,r \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $1\leq r<u$. So, $n^{k-1}.1=mu.1+r.1\implies 0=0+r.1\implies r.1=0$,i.e $\text{ch} \ F<u$, which is not possible.

So, $u$ must divide $n^{k-1}$, further, $u$ being a prime it must divide $n$.

Conversely, let $\text{ch} \ F \mid n$. Now, $A^2=(a'_{ij})_{n \times n}$ where $a'_{ij}=n=0$ for all $1\leq i,j\leq n$. Hence $A^2=O_{n \times n}$.

***Is this correct?***

Comment: The induction is OK but you don't need it. Once you know $A^2=nA$ you have $A^{k+1}=A^2A^{k-1}=nAA^{k-1}=nA^k$.

Comment: A field of non-zero characteristic  need not be finite.

Comment: @AnginaSeng corrected.